# How do I save a WordPress website into different server?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, web, fatal-error

I have been having trouble saving a WordPress website into a different server and keep getting an error when opening it in my browser.

Fatal error:

> Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   32245 bytes) in
>   /home/clemente1234/public_html/clementeghuerta.com/green-banker-2/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 347

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you "saving into a different server"? There are a number of different WordPress plugins available for transferring from one server to another, including transferring both files (e.g., media) and the WP database tables.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing can typically be resolved by adjusting how much memory is being allocated to WordPress. In your wp-config.php file, try modifying/adding this line to an appropriate amount of memory. The current limit seems to be at about 67M, so maybe something like:

`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only have 64M.

If you have access to your php.ini, increase the max memory size..

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Or even in your .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```